# Highlight entire line with ctrl-shift-left or ctrl-shift-right

Tags: shortcut-keys

I am used to using a MacBook where you can do Command-shift-left/right to highlight an entire line of text. Is there any way I can do the same thing in Ubuntu?

For example, lets say my cursor is here:

```
some exampl|e text
```

I want to be able to highlight "some exampl" not just "exampl" when I press ctrl-shift-left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, welcome to Linux!  I, too, transferred from Mac to Linux years ago, and I think it's a great way to transition.

In Ubuntu, as you've already discovered,

`Shift` + `Home` = select where the cursor currently is, to the beginning of the line.

`Shift` + `End` = select where the cursor currently is, to the end of the line.

You can also use `Home` and `End` on their own to simply move the cursor, and not select text.

These are some other shortcuts you might find helpful as well:

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Home` = select from where the cursor currently is to the very beginning of the file/document.

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `End` = select from where the cursor currently is to the very end of the file/document.

You can also use `Ctrl` + `A` to select all text in the document as well.

In addition, you can simply hold `Shift` down and use the `arrow keys` to select text as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice answer! Great job highlighting all the different shortcuts. Do you know how one would change those shortcuts to be more mac-like?

Comment: It's been a while since I have been on Mac!  I had to refer to this link https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236  And from there, it looks like the Opt key is used instead of Ctrl.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:
It's not `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Home` but just `Shift`+`Home`!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing coming from Mac. A workaround is to use `Ctrl+Shift+Down` to highlight from the cursor to the end of line (including the  carriage return).  And `Ctrl+Shift+Up` to highlight from the cursor to the end of the previous line. Not perfect, but better than nothing.